# Python create list from CSV

Tags: python, csv, scripting

I am trying to build a python list from a CSV file. My CSV file has 5 columns as shown below separated by pipe(|):

```
QTP|Install|C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Install|Sequence
QTP|Open   |C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Open   |Sequence
QTP|Install|C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Install|Parallel
QTP|Install|C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Install|Parallel
QTP|Install|C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Install|Parallel
QTP|Open   |C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Open   |Sequence
QTP|Install|C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Install|Sequence
QTP|Open   |C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Open   |Parallel
QTP|Open   |C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Open   |Parallel
QTP|Open   |C:\Cone_Automation\RunTest.vbs|Open   |Parallel
```

Above are my test cases in CSV.

I want to build a list based on the last column of the file. 
I want a list as, if first two lines are having the text "sequence" in column[4], then I should get the complete line in list `Seq1`.

If line 3rd, 4th and 5th is having `Parallel` then I should get the complete 3rd, 4th and 5th records in list `Par1`.

Then after that, if I am having `Sequence`  in line 6th and 7th then I should get the list in `Seq2`.

After that, if I am having the text as `Parallel` then I should get the list as `Par2`.

How can I achieve this using Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need separated `seq1` and `seq2` or will there be `seq3` and so on, but here is how you can check your file:

```
import csv

seq1 = []
par1 = []
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar=' ')
    for row in r:
        if row[-1] == "Sequence":
            seq1.append(row)
        else:
            par1.append(row)

print seq1
print par1
```

Output:

```
[['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Sequence'], ['QTP', 'Open   ', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Open   ', 'Sequence'], ['QTP', 'Open   ', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Open   ', 'Sequence'], ['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Sequence']]
[['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Parellel'], ['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Parellel'], ['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Parellel'], ['QTP', 'Open   ', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Open   ', 'Parellel'], ['QTP', 'Open   ', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Open   ', 'Parellel'], ['QTP', 'Open   ', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Open   ', 'Parellel']]
```

So if you need to separate them, then just add if statements when appending to the list

---

Maybe instead of creating a lot of variable like seq1, seq2 and etc. you can create directory of list? For example:

```
import csv

d = {}
countSequence = 1
countParallel = 1

with open('kres.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar=' ')
    for row in r:
        if row[-1] == "Sequence":
            d["seq" + str(countSequence)] = row
            countSequence += 1
        else:
            d["par" + str(countParallel)] = row
            countParallel += 1

print d["seq1"]
```

Output:

```
['QTP', 'Install', 'C:\\Cone_Automation\\RunTest.vbs', 'Install', 'Sequence']
```

So if you need second parallel group, you just call it like this:

```
print d["par2"]
```

Comment: I need the seq1,then par1,then seq2 then par2 as if they appear in the csv rows.These are the test cases which i need to run sequentially if they are sequence work and then parallel if they have parllel word. SO if my 50 test cases are in parellel  then i am going to execute it on parellel mahines. SO i need the list as it appeares in the csv. FOr eg if first 10 test cases are sequencial then it should go in seq1. then if next 30 casesin parrlel then it should go in par1. Then again if 5 are in seq then it should go in seq2 and likewise. This is how i want it THanks again for your reply.

Comment: Yes.It depends upon how many parallel and sequential blocks of test cases we are providing. But if I am able to generate 2 par and 2 seq lists then that would also help.

Comment: Updated answer, please check if it will suit you

Answer (score 0):

[Google - Python CVS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar=' ')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Where `row` is a list containing the objects on that row.
You can append row to another list giving your perhaps what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Thanks for your reply. Here how I did it.

import csv

class RecordDetails:
    Token = ""
    Records = []

csv_file = 'E:\\Automation_STAF\\AutomationDriver.csv'
testList = list(csv.reader(open(csv_file, 'r')))
curToken = "null"

recordDetails = RecordDetails()
recordDetails=None
records = [RecordDetails]

for index, line in enumerate(testList):
    token="null"
    token = testList[index][4]

    if token=="null":
        continue
    if curToken !=token:
        curToken =token
        recordDetails = RecordDetails()
        recordDetails.Token = curToken
        recordDetails.Records=[]
        records.append(recordDetails)
    if recordDetails!=None:
        recordDetails.Records.append(line)

    #print(line)

#print(len(records))
#seq1=records[1].Records
#seq2=records[2].Records
#seq3=records[3].Records
#print(seq3)
d={}
CountSequence=1
#Listcount = len(records)
for i, obj in enumerate(records):
    if records[i].Token=="Sequence":
        d["seq" + str(CountSequence)] =records[i].Records
        CountSequence +=1
    if records[i].Token=="Parallel":
        d["par" + str(CountSequence)] =records[i].Records
        CountSequence +=1
print(len(records))
print (d["seq1"])
print (d["par2"])
print (d["seq3"])


Now here I am able to get all the directory of list. Thank you again for your help.
```